# having trouble with left join LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, datatable, left-join

I have two DataTables `t1` and `t2`.  I'm trying to perform a LINQ left join, multiple equijoin, to get the DataRows in `t1` that are not in `t2`.

In SQL, what I'm trying to accomplish is:

```
select t1.* 
from t1
left join t2
on t1.a=t2.a and
   t1.b=t2.b and
   t1.c=t2.c
where
   t2.a is null
```

So far I have the following:

```
public DataTable t1_without_t2(DataTable t1, DataTable t2)
        {
            var query = from t1_row in t1.AsEnumerable()
                        join t2_row in t2.AsEnumerable()
                        on 
                        new { t_a = t1_row["a"], t_b = t1_row["b"], t_c = t1_row["c"]}   
                        equals
                        new { t_a = t2_row["a"], t_b = t2_row["b"], t_c = t2_row["c"]}
                        into leftJoinT1withoutT2
                        from join_row in leftJoinT1withoutT2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        where t2_row["a"] == null
                        select new
                        {
                            j_a = join_row["a"],
                            j_b = join_row["b"],
                            j_c = join_row["c"],
                        };
            DataTable dt = t1.Clone();
            foreach (var result in query)
            {
                dt.LoadDataRow(
                    new object[]
                    {
                        result.j_a,
                        result.j_b,
                        result.j_c
                    },
                    false);
            }
            return dt;
        }
```

This is failing on the line `j_a = join_row["a"]` with this message: 
`Column 'a' does not belong to table.`

I thought that the `into leftJoinT1withoutT2` line was supposed to put the results of the join into a var with the column structure of table `t1`, from which the non-matching entries would be removed using `where t2_row["a"] == null` .  Is that not what's happening here?  I'm a little confused.

Comment: Your query does not compile

Comment: @KonstantinVasilcov, yes, the `where t2_row["a"]==null` line. sorry, I had commented that line out while trying to debug this.  i don't know why it's not compiling, shouldn't `t2_row` be visible at that level of the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should look like this:

```
var query = from t1_row in t1.AsEnumerable()
            join t2_row in t2.AsEnumerable()
            on
            new { t_a = t1_row["a"], t_b = t1_row["b"], t_c = t1_row["c"] }
            equals
            new { t_a = t2_row["a"], t_b = t2_row["b"], t_c = t2_row["c"] }
            into leftJoinT1withoutT2
            from join_row in leftJoinT1withoutT2.DefaultIfEmpty()
                                                .Where(r => r == null)
            select new
            {
                j_a = t1_row["a"],
                j_b = t1_row["b"],
                j_c = t1_row["c"],
            };
```

Have a look at [How to: Perform Left Outer Joins (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx).

The `join_row` gets `null` (i.e. default `TSource` value, see [Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360179.aspx)) when there is no matching element in `t2`, while `t1_row` always contains the joined value. So as far as you need only those rows for which `join_row` is `null`, I used `.Where(r => r == null)`.